# Netbeans Gradle config

Tags: gradle, netbeans-7

I started using netbeans, and I'm setting up a gradle project.
I want to control what task is used when I use netbeans' "run" command.
It is defaulting to run "gradle run", but I want to pass in something other than "run".
I cannot find where to do that, is there a place edit "gradle run" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust all the built-in commands in the project properties: "Manage Built-In Tasks". For details see the wiki about [project properties](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/wiki/Project-Properties) and [built in tasks](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/wiki/Build-Commands). If you prefer, you may add several "profiles" each with different build commands.